# The column name is not valid in springboot

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring, spring-boot

I wrote native query but I'm getting an error:

> The column name covidSymptomId is not valid.

What's wrong?

[There are table in mssql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka8Eh.png)

[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NK0E.png)

CovidSymptom.java

```
 @Data
 @AllArgsConstructor
 @NoArgsConstructor
 @Entity
 @Table(name="CovidSymptom")
 public class CovidSymptom {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "covidSymptomId")
private int id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "covidId")
private Covid covidSymptom;

@Column(name = "symptom")
private String symptom;
}
```

CovidSymptomDao.java

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true,value = "Select symptom From CovidSymptom GROUP BY symptom order by count(covidSymptomId) desc")
List<CovidSymptom> getMost3SymptomOffCovid();
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: I would try to remove the column name annotation for covidSymptomId and just use the default id name that the column will get branded with when you use the @id annotation

Comment: What value would you show for that column? You are aggregating by a different column, so either you select an aggregation such as `COUNT` or `MIN`, or you remove the association.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include all columns that are mapped in your query. So:

```
Select covidSymptomId, symptom....
```

Comment: Now I'm getting " Column 'CovidSymptom.covidSymptomId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." this error.

Comment: @Kadri That's because you are aggregating, and that column is not in the `GROUP BY` so it needs an aggregation function

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're getting a column name problem, since your select query returns a list of "symptom"(String), whilst your method provides a list of "CovidSymptom" (Object).